# How to find intersect of two curves in matlab?

Tags: matlab, intersection, curve

I have two series of data in matlab (for example `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]`).

I plotted two curves and want to find their exact intersection point. The intersection point may not be an exact point of from `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]`, so should be calculated.

It is not possible to fit a curve for the points and using `fsolve` function, because the points' behavior is not known.

Is there a solution in Matlab to find the exact intersection point?

Comment: Could you not create some interpolation function between the data points, then solve for intersections? You need to be posting what code you've *tried* here...

Comment: The answer will completely depend on what kind of interpolation you want to use. But, in general, you could  `fsolve` for a `fit` through the data.

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: Have you tried using `intersect` command ?